# Nested shortcode wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function, nested, shortcode

I have the following code:

```
[video mp4="http://www.mysite/vid.mp4" poster="[imgurl]"][/video]
```

For `[imgurl]` I use:

```
function img_url() {
  echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $saved_post_id ) );

}
add_shortcode('imgurl', 'img_url');
```

Can you give an advice to make my code works?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your img_url function. The problem is that WordPress will not parse this as you expect. Specifically,  it will not see the shortcode '[imgurl]'. See 'Square Brackets' in the 'Limitations' section of https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API. To fix this problem you can write your own video shortcode function which will call the builtin video shortcode and your imgurl shortcode.